# PySpark - reducyByKey on a (tuple,int) value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have the RDD:

[image: key,((tuple),int)]

I want to reduce it to each key and its average per point in the tuple.
For example if I have (small example):

```
[(1,((0,19,15,39),1)),(1,((0,64,19,3),1))]
```

I will get:

```
[(1,(0,83,34,41),2))]
```

then (or directly)

```
[(1,(0,41.5,17,21)]
```

I tried:

```
reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
reduceByKey(lambda a,b: (a[0]+b[0],a[1]+b[1]))
```

and other stuff that didn't helped or gave RDD error.

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some further calculations to get the average per key:

```
result = rdd.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: (tuple(i+j for (i,j) in zip(a[0],b[0])), a[1]+b[1])) \
            .map(lambda r: (r[0], tuple(i/r[1][1] for i in r[1][0])))
```